Is a snowflake schema in a data warehouse well designed if dimensions are connected to another dimension?
We want to define a snowflake schema for a data warehouse for the following dimensions and fact:

Dim Hospital: ID, name, city_id, city_name, city_inhab, province_id, province_name, province_inhab, state_id, state_name, state_area
Dim Patient: ID, name, city_id, city_name, city_inhab, province_id, province_name, province_inhab, state_id, state_name, state_area
Dim Doctor: ID, name, city_id, city_name, city_inhab, province_id, province_name, province_inhab, state_id, state_name, state_area
Fact Visit: wait, duration, cost

Which of the following is a better option for a snowflake schema?

To define a common City dimension related to its Province dimension related to its State dimension, and relate the City dimension to Hospital, Patient and Doctor.
To define a different City dimension related to its different Province dimension related to its different State dimension for each of the orginal dimensions (Hospital, Patient and Doctor)

Thanks!

Since the locations have different meanings, look into using Outriggers

Outriggers are tables or entities that are shared by more than one dimension.
    
        — IBM

Here's an example use: with a Starflake Schema

